# Type II Error for One-Sample Z test

Tags: statistics

Im having a lot of trouble with this question. I have attempted this question multiple times but im not getting the correct outcome. Help would be greatly appreciated. statistic question in the link,

[image]

an answer asap would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Here is part (a), easier to read:
Consider a random sample of size $n = 25$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma = 7.5).$ When testing $H_0: \mu = 50$ against $H_a: \mu > 50$ at level $\alpha = 0.01$, find the probability of type II error for alternative value $\mu_a = 54;$
that is, find $\beta(54).$

Comment: Most people find such phrasing somewhat rude and your question is presented context. This does not 
match [users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To 
prevent that, please [edit] the question to include your thoughts and the work you have done so 
far to solve the problem. For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, 
and what your thoughts on it are because it prevents people from telling you things you already know, and helps them 
give their answers at the right level. Furthermore, please avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures
cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: It is also a good thing to invest a minute to take [the tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to ask questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: **OMG: Another smudgy cell phone image!** I have edited a more readable
version of part (a) at the end of your post. If you disagree with it, please re-edit. Parts (b) and (c) are repetitious, so help on part (a) should suffice.

Comment: What is this, your fifth account on this site now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test statistic is $Z = \frac{\bar X - 50}{7.5/\sqrt{25}},$ and you
reject $H_0$ at the 1% level for $Z \ge 2.326.$

With a bit of algebra, that means to reject $H_0$ if $\bar X \ge 53.489.$

Now the type II error for $\mu_a = 54$ is failing to reject if the population distribution
is $\mathsf{Norm}(54, 7.5).$ Thus
$\beta(54) = P(\bar X < 53.489),$ where $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(54, 7.5/5=1.5).$  By standardizing and using printed tables of the standard normal CDF or by using software (such as R statistical software below), you can find $\beta(54) = 0.3334.$

```
 pnorm(53.489, 54, 1.5)
 [1] 0.3666773
```

Checking this in the 'power and sample size' procedure of Minitab 17, one has:

```
Power and Sample Size  

1-Sample Z Test

Testing mean = null (versus > null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.01  Assumed standard deviation = 7.5

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         4      25  0.633192     # alternative 54
         6      25  0.952901     # alternative 56
```

[image]

Because the power $\pi(54) = 1 - \beta(54),$ we see that $\pi(54) = .633$ is in
agreement with the answer above, within rounding error.